# Google cardboard: Using a bluetooth remote trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

We have developed a VR game using Google Cardboard and unity. Now we need to have the same game work on the headset below. Everything seems fine except of cause the trigger. Which is based on a bluetooth connection and obvious does not tap the screen to send a trigger event.

I have tried looking for the setting Tap to Trigger, which seems to have vanished from my cardboard object (or is simply not in the latest SDK).

Also tried to look for the manufacturer of this viewer but to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea how generally this is done in unity 3d.

[image]